# How to create Facebook or instagram Tabbed layout in android

Tags: android, facebook

can someone help me with a tutorial or a clue on how to achieve this kind of [instagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuQMp.png) or [Facebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScacZ.png) tabbed layout (the part circled).

Comment: This is not a tutorial site. Google will be your best friend during these times. When you begin to write some code and have a specific question regarding code, that's where we're here to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Top Tabs: http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Bottom tabs: https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation -or- https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar

Comment: @user6073313 no prob :)